# Change the COLORRANGE parameter in MapServer using URL parameters

Tags: mapserver

To change COLOR am using this `[${layerName}.CLASS[index].STYLE[index]]: COLOR 255 145`

but it does not work for COLORRANGE.

Comment: What MapServer version do you use?

Comment: Hi tanks, I am currently using mapserver version 7.6

Comment: `COLOR 255 145` isn't a colour, you need another number for the Blue component.  For `COLORRANGE` you need two colours like: `COLORRANGE 255 255 178 189 0 38`

Comment: that's what i do but it doesn't work.

Comment: I receive an error. "Internal Server Error
" The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: http: //localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/path/to/your/mapfile.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=layername&YEAR=2021&TILED=true&map.layer[layernamel].CLASS[0].STYLE[0]=COLORRANGE%20255%20255%20178%20189%200%2038&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&BBOX=-8766409.899970295%2C-2504688.542848654%2C-7514065.628545967%2C-1252344.2714243263

Comment: It may be good to know for the future that starting from MapServer 8 the syntax that you use is deprecated https://mapserver.org/cgi/controls.html#using-mapserver-version-8 and the runtime substitutions https://mapserver.org/cgi/runsub.html#runsub may not include COLORRANGE. Maybe you should ask from the mapserver-users list if there is some solution that would work also with MapServer 8.